# Finding Network overshoots under a certain distance

Tags: fme-form, network

we have a large contiguous network that will have legitimate overshoots (like a dead end street), but may or may not have illegitimate overshoots.  Using FME, I can't seem to manufacture a way to find these overshoots.  It is new to me, but I cannot work out how to do it.  A long lunch yesterday for Mothering Sunday may have removed a large number of brain cells, but I can't work out a way to do it.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flag the true one ways and no through streets through your attributes - use the length transformer and calculate the distances - test for that distance and exclude them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [SmartCleaner (get transformer from here)](http://fmestore.safe.com/transformers/SmartCleaner.htm) When fixing dangles. Another option would be [MRFClener](http://www.safe.com/about/news/press/archive/85/) it's very good but costs.

Comment: Thanks Simplexio.  I did look at Smartcleaner, but that deletes the links, which I will use to clean it, but I want to note them first, report on them.  We don't have the license for MRF though!

Comment: Yeah . that MRF lisence is expensive. You can open SmartCleaner and see how it does magic. It's just CustomeTransformer after all.

Comment: How do you open it all up @simplexio?

Comment: add Smartcleaner_2013 from FME store  to your workspace and right click it. Choose Edit, edit and close window